# consulta dividiendo filas por rango de fechas

Tags: mysql

Buen dia, necesito realizar la consulta que muestre el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi consulta:

```
  SELECT ''Ciudad,''Sucursal,t2.periodo as 'Ingresos',''Aprobadas
from invex t1
LEFT JOIN gral_semanas_año t2 ON date( t1.Fecha_de_venta ) = t2.fecha 
where date(t1.Fecha_de_venta) BETWEEN '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-08'
group by t2.periodo
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
  t1.ciudad,
    T1.Call_center,
    count( T1.Call_center ) AS 'Ingresos',
    COUNT( IF ( T1.Estado_de_venta = 'APROBADA', 1, NULL ) ) 'Aprobadas'
    FROM invex t1
    LEFT JOIN gral_semanas_año t2 ON date( t1.Fecha_de_venta ) = t2.fecha 
    where date(t1.Fecha_de_venta) BETWEEN '2019-12-01' and '2019-12-08'
GROUP BY
    t1.Call_center
    ORDER BY t2.periodo,t1.ciudad) Tabla1;

el resultado que me da es el siguiente:
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el resultado es el que acabo de poner pero si pongo una fecha más y abarca otro rango se coloca sobre la misma columna y yo lo quiero dividir,alguien me puede apoyar ya que necesito que se divida por el rango de días

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lo que vos queres hacer lo tiene que resolver la vista, no la consulta

Comment: gracias, ya revise lo de la pregunta y si la formule mal disculpa, como en la vista?? me podrias explicar como se haria una vista, lo guardo ese resultado en una tabla y despues hago la vista???

Comment: no, por vista me refiero a la salida por donde ves los datos. Tu query devuelve todos los registros que necesitas y tu soft que muestra esos datos los ordena en pantalla como vos queres. Si no, tenes que tratar de hacer una tabla pivotante (que no es facil) y para colmo con multiples pivotes